# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException on server with the path from local machine

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, deployment

I have created a web api with c# .net core 3.1 and I use a directory to save generated invoices there. the path to the directory on my local machine is C:\CU World\Backend\CU-API\CU-API\Generated Invoices\

On my local machine the api works fine. But on my linux server it does not work... I'm getting this error:

[image]

I do not understand why I am getting this error when I publish this to linux server with apache2 installed on it. Can somebody help me, and expain me how to fix it?

Comment: do you have any hard coded paths or anything in the configuration files?

Comment: oh thats just the symbols. thats why you see that.

Comment: doe the path on the first line actually exist?

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes I created the directory on my linux server as well under the path on the first line. In my code I always used relative path like that: document.GeneratePdf(env.ContentRootPath + "/GeneratedInvoices/" + invoiceName + ".pdf");

Comment: avoid using string concat for path names - use `Path.Join`.

Comment: @DanielA.White I still getting the same error. I republished the code in vs, and uploaded it to the server. and even restarted the service on linux

Comment: Please post all the code that's used to generate the path.

Comment: The following may be useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524632(v=vs.90)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix it by adding this to my Startp.cs

```
var fileProviderPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FILE_PROVIDER_PATH");
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
     FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(fileProviderPath),
     RequestPath = "/GeneratedInvoices"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was worked me is to to add the `<Content>` tag to the .csproj file as you can see below

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    ...
    <ItemGroup>
        ...
        <Content Include="photos\*">
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```